# Determining iOS app entitlements at run time

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

Is there a way to determine/test permitted app capabilities at run time? I know how and where to set these in Xcode - that's not the issue. I would like to be able to check the permitted app capabilities when running on the phone to make sure the app was signed appropriately. And yes, I know I can check the permitted capabilities for the signing profile, I just want to make totally sure what is going on.